How to set chain weight of Cycling Power Control Point using react-native-ble-plx library
I'm testing this on Tacx Neo 2T 07668.
here are the list of service UUIDs of the device.

00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (GAP Service)
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (GATT service)
00001816-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Cycling Speed and Cadence)
00001818-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Cycling Power)
6e40fec1-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
0000fe59-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Nordic Semiconductor ASA)
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Device Information)
cf285001-00db-15a1-0e3f-ffa5794c3719
fa1c030e-52d1-2062-0777-bc61f0b8e27b

and below is the list of characteristics for Cycling Power

Cycling Power Measurement : 0x2a63
Cycling Power Feature : 0x2a65
Sensor Location : 0x2a5d
Cycling Power Vector : 0x2a64
Cycling Power Control Point : 0x2a66

I found that the Cycling Power Control Point is the only writable property so I thought this might be capable of changing the resistance of the device. so I looked up on the GATT specification (https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/gatt-specification-supplement/GATT_Specification_Supplement.pdf)
Op Code Value of 0x08 has the 'SetChainWeight' parameter.
so I let chatGpt write some code for me to change the chain weight but it doesn't seem to work. any ideas?
const changeResistance = async resistance => {
    const opCode = 0x08;
    // Op Code for Set Chain Weight
    const chainWeightBytes = new Uint8Array(new Uint16Array([resistance]).buffer,);
    const command = new Uint8Array([opCode, ...chainWeightBytes]);
    const commandBase64 = Buffer.from(command).toString('base64');
    try {
      // await bleManager.connectToDevice(connectedDevice.data[0].id);
      await bleManager.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristicsForDevice(connectedDevice.data[0].id);
      await bleManager.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForDevice(
        connectedDevice.data[0].id,
        CYCLING_POWER.serviceUUID,
        CYCLING_POWER.characterUUID.cyclingPowerControlPoint,
        commandBase64,
      );
      console.log('Chain weight set successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to set chain weight:', error);
    }
  };

When I ride and execute the code. no resistance applied. no errors returned. please help.
when i add 100 for resistance. i get [8, 100, 0] for command.
when i add 10000 for resistance, i get [8, 16, 39] for command.
